# Is there a function that could find slope of a curve ignoring peaks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, statsmodels

Let's say I obtained a timeserie (in blue) (with some missing data) that is (as far as i understood) :
- following a general trend between specific points
- more or less cyclic

[image: Curves]

I have drawn the red curve myself. I need to find a way to obtain it in **realtime**...
I mean, that even when I am in peak in the middle of the graph, it should show me the red line.

I want to use machine learning (tf, sklearn or statsmodel) to learn from few curves and identify the new one in **realtime**...

Have anyone faces the same kind of problem ?

**Notes :**

1. Realtime mean that i d'ont have the full input (blue). ie I have it until may 17 10:00, i have to find the output (red) at may 17 10:00.
2. There no model for getting red from blue... In fact, peaks have to be ignore to get the red curve.
3. The zeros come from the fact that there is a big change in the blue curve, and the red curve's "origin" will change and go up

Comment: 1) Don't get what you mean by real time. but lets assume you want input(blue) -> output(red). 2) What do the red curves mean? Minimum? Trend? Derivative? Average? Is there a model that gets red from blue? 3) Where do the zeros in the red curve come from? Missing data? 4) Looks more like something you should ask on  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ 5) I would just use a window averaging/minimum function to draw the red graph. 6) IF you really want to do machine learning. Its input -> NN -> output. And thats it.

Comment: I will try my best to answer inside my post...

Comment: Well I don't actually know what would be the ideal scenario and without underlying knowledge on what the red curve represents, I would simply try a deep neural network predicting output values. Inputs would be current value, derivatives describing the slope (I would use a window) and outputting a single float. No guarantees it will work, but your problem seems to be quite a complex one.Your zero explanation makes 0 sense btw. Contradictions in second last and 4th last red curve 0. PS. Maybe you should just try a LPF.